# Comparing any of these value from an array Efficiently

Tags: java

I am having an Array of String of 10 elements.
Now I need to compare my value available in any of these Arrays value.

> 1 Option I thought of sorting the array and then binary search on the
>   same

But further analysis, I found the value needed to be compare is not exactly same, it contains some value , but even in that case, it should be successful.

Like Value to compare ,

```
String str = "Author"
String[] arrays = {"@Author","@Auth",@Au...}
```

str.contains(arrays..) actually but how to do the same .

Comment: What would be the size of array in worst case ?

Comment: around 1000 in rarest scenario

Comment: Then simply go sequentially and do `contains` check, if you try to remove the padding character or if you write your own comparator to ignore that character it would add computation cost, so simple contains fits good here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Dynamic Programming:

```
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Common_Subsequence
```

this algorithm check the longest subsequence of string with the minimum complex

This is the algor in java:

```
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/LCS.java.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with an array with only 10 elements... you don't need to worry about efficiency!

You can simply loop through the entire array, or instead of using a `String[]` use an `List<string>` and use the contains method.

Comment: the contains method of the ArrayList wouldn't work in this case cause the value is not exactly the same, the best solution as far is to loop through the entire array.